# adding varchar with decimals php

Tags: php, floating-point, type-conversion, addition

```
  int    varchar
+======+==========+
| id   | amount   |
+======+==========+
| 1    | 1.40     |
| 2    | 2.40     |
| 3    | 3.40     |
+======+==========+


$res += $row['amount'];
// $res = 6


$res += (float)$row['amount'];
// $res = 6
```

how come i can't add them?

Comment: huh? Are you trying to add all amounts in `amount`? How is `$res=6` true?

Comment: Just select your text and press the `{}` button in the toolbar to mark it as code. No need for `&nbsp;` and `<br>`s.

Comment: @Paul yes im adding all of them

Comment: SHow us more of your code, such as the db quesry and the whole of your loop

Comment: Can you show `var_dump($row['amount'])`?

Comment: @xdazz here are some var_dumps `string(8) "1,000.00" string(8) "2,391.45" string(8) "2,005.31"`

Comment: OK, strip the commas before you try casting to anything.... else the cast will stop at the first non-digit-or-decimal-point character it hits... and if you'd shown us the real numeric values in the first place(instead of 1.4, 2.4, 3.4), you'd have got your answer a lot more quickly

Comment: @xdazz thx a lot :D just getting rid of the comma(,) helped me a lot..

Comment: What answer do you WANT? 6 or 7.2?

Comment: You should not store numeric values as `VARCHAR` in the database. Store them as decimals, that what they're for. That would've avoided this problem too.

Comment: You're aware that there's a decimal type for table columns though?

Comment: @deceze: simultaneous comment :)

Comment: in fact you should not use decimal at all here .. if its money, just use the smallest possible unit (like cents) and only divide that by 100 when you display the final result of your calculations. If you don't do you start dealing with floating point issues and sooner or later you will sit hours hunting for a `"where is this stupid +/- 1 cent bug hidden"` issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your var_dump results `string(8) "1,000.00" string(8) "2,391.45" string(8) "2,005.31"`, this is the problem of your data.

`(float)"2,391.45"` will cast the string `string("2,391.45")` to  `float(2)`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP floating point numbers cannot contain comma: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

```
LNUM          [0-9]+
DNUM          ([0-9]*[\.]{LNUM}) | ({LNUM}[\.][0-9]*)
EXPONENT_DNUM [+-]?(({LNUM} | {DNUM}) [eE][+-]? {LNUM})
```